Cannot see filesystem logs in Azure Function App using Consumption plan with Linux and dotnet-isolated
I have an Azure Function App that logs to Application Insights in Azure, but I'm unable to see any console logs (see image below).
During local development using Azure Functions Core Tools, I see console logs printed using ILogger<T>.LogInformation() etc.
Normally, when I inspect the filesystem logs for Premium Azure Function Apps, "Connected!" is printed, and then another statement immediately follows. However, here it hangs on "Connected!".
How can I successfully view the filesystem logs on the Consumption plan with Linux and dotnet-isolated?
Code:
var host = new HostBuilder()
    .ConfigureFunctionsWebApplication((context, builder) => { })
    .ConfigureAppConfiguration((context, builder) =>
    {
        var environment = context.Configuration.GetValue<string>("ENVIRONMENT", "development");

        builder.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
            .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{environment}.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
            .AddEnvironmentVariables();
    })
    .ConfigureServices((context, services) =>
    {
        services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetryWorkerService();
        services.ConfigureFunctionsApplicationInsights();
        services.Configure<WorkerOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.EnableUserCodeException = true;
        });
        ...
    })
    .ConfigureLogging(builder =>
    {
        builder.Services.Configure<LoggerFilterOptions>(options =>
        {
            // Default ApplicationInsights logging filter
            LoggerFilterRule defaultRule = options.Rules.FirstOrDefault(rule => rule.ProviderName
                == "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ApplicationInsights.ApplicationInsightsLoggerProvider");
            if (defaultRule is not null)
            {
                options.Rules.Remove(defaultRule);
            }
        });
        builder.AddFilter<ApplicationInsightsLoggerProvider>("", LogLevel.Information);
    })
    .Build();



I have tried the same in my environment with your code and also a sample .NET 8.0 isolated Azure Function, but unable to see the File System logs.
It looks like File System logs are not supported in Linux Azure function with consumption plan.
I could fetch only the Application Logs in Function App's Console in Portal.
If you are trying to fetch the Application Insights logs in Console of function App, select App Insights Logs from the drop down as shown below and run the function:
App Logs:

Connected! You are now viewing logs of Function runs in the current Code + Test panel. To see all the logs for this Function, please go to 'Logs' from the Function menu.
2024-10-01T12:25:52Z   [Information]   Executing 'Functions.Function1' (Reason='This function was programmatically called via the host APIs.', Id=8c73e711-d33a-4933-9104-16b9d3830743)
2024-10-01T12:25:53Z   [Information]   C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.
2024-10-01T12:25:53Z   [Information]   Executing OkObjectResult, writing value of type 'System.String'.
2024-10-01T12:25:53Z   [Information]   Executed 'Functions.Function1' (Succeeded, Id=8c73e711-d33a-4933-9104-16b9d3830743, Duration=1024ms)

The same logs can be fetched in Function App=>Log Stream:


Thank you for letting me know. You say It looks like File System logs are not supported in Linux Azure function with consumption plan. - have you seen this documented anywhere? I have spend considerable amount of time trying to get it to work

I could fetch only the Application Logs in Function App's Console in Portal. - This should be "Application Insights Logs". Yes, I can fetch Application Insights logs. That works...
